# Add own macros to ".emacs"

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using KOMA-script, which offers the use of letter-class-options, which can be stored in a file: *.lco.

One command I define in a "zrp.lco" is very simple:

```
\newcommand{\Beweis}[1]{Beweis: #1}
```

Now I'd like to teach Emacs to know about this command. I tried to put into my .emacs:

```
 (TeX-add-style-hook
      "zrp"
      (lambda ()
        (TeX-add-symbols
     '("Beweis" 1))))
```

But Emacs spills out an error while loading:

```
eval-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-add-style-hook
```

What is wrong?

Comment: TeX-add-style-hook is defined in auctex, presumably you are doing this too early (I just ran your code in my scratch buffer without error)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, thank you. But loading AUCTeX directly is not possible, (require 'auctex) inside .emacs gives an error. So what I probably need is a kind of hook: if AUCTeX is loaded, run this code...

Comment: Wrap an `eval-after-load "tex"` around `TeX-add-style-hook`.

Comment: or put it in LaTeX-mode-hook

Comment: @giordano & DavidCarlisle Please, could you just give that as an answer with the whole wrap, be it either eval or hook? I don't speak lisp and I could accept your answer then :-))

Comment: `eval-after-load` sounds safer to initialise a variable session-wise. With a `hook`, the code will be run everytime you open a new file, and the variable may get cluttered with instances of your command.

Comment: On the other hand, `auctex` has a powerful auto-parsing mechanism for such user-defined commands, it might be an even better idea to investigate how to get it to parse your `.lco` files.

Comment: @T.Verron true, It is however the first thing suggested in the auctex info page on customization:-)

Comment: @T.Verron I'd be happy about a hack to make AUCTeX parse specific files. Another solution would be to transfer my definitions from the lco to a regular *.sty file and go the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way to add support for a new style file is to create a style hook file, as explained in the [AUCTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Hacking-the-Parser).

Note that you can autogenerate the style hook file for a *TeX source issuing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-auto-generate` <kbd>RET</kbd>, see [Automatic Customization for a User](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Automatic-Private).

If you want to put your style hook inside your `.emacs`, you have to insert it inside an `eval-after-load` so it will be run only when AUCTeX is loaded.  In particular, your code should be changed to

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (TeX-add-style-hook
      "zrp"
      (lambda ()
    (TeX-add-symbols
     '("Beweis" 1))))))
```

Note that the hook defined will be automatically executed only if there is an explicit

```
\usepackage{zrp}
```

in your LaTeX code, otherwise you have to use

```lisp
(TeX-run-style-hooks "zrp")
```

to run it.

Answer (score 1):

After switching to AucTeX 11.88 I took a second look at the matter. TeX-add-style-hook now has a [third argument](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2014-10/msg00019.html) and I found this simple solution for my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
    (TeX-add-symbols
      '("Beweis" 1)
      '("AnlageK" t)
      '("AnlageB" t)
      '("signed" 1)
      )))
```

If a wiser man / woman notices a drawback of this solution, please leave a comment.